# Is there a connection method for cucumber/webrat to use a socks5 connection

Tags: cucumber, socks

The host I'd like to test with cucumber is behind a proxy. Using a standart connection e.g. Webrat::Session.new doesn't work because the proxy in the middle ignores my hostheader.
I need a connection in Cucumber which is similar to this curl command:

curl http://www.whatever-test.com/index.html -H "host: www.whatever.com"  --socks5 proxy.tunnel.com:333